# How to modify an array and convert it to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have an array:

```
[ 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3' ]
```

I need the final result to be

```
{ 'Item 1':true, 'Item 2':true, 'Item 3':true }
```

Using ES6 I got kinda close with this:

```
        let arr = [];
        for (let m of crmData.modRequired) {
            let i = m + ':true';
            arr.push(i);
        }
        modReq = JSON.stringify(arr);
        modReq = modReq.replace(/\[/, '{');
        modReq = modReq.replace(/\]/, '}');
```

But that produced: 
`{"Quotes:true","Flight Logs:true","Currency Records:true","FTD:true","Maintenance Tracker:true"}`

Comment: uhm... well, don't. convert it to an array, create a new object based on it, then stringify it.

Comment: Right: map the array into an array of objects and then pass it through `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this very easily with `Object.assign` and `Array.map`, like so:

The idea is to map your array of values into an array of objects that follow the `{"ItemX": true}` pattern, and then combine them into a single object using `Object.assign`.

```js
var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];

var mapped = Object.assign({}, ...items.map(item => ({[item]: true})));

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using the array `.reduce` method. That will turn the array into the object you want. Then you can use `JSON.stringify` to transform that into a json string.

```js
const myArray = [ 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3' ]

// I need the final result to be
// { 'Item 1':true, 'Item 2':true, 'Item 3':true }

const myObj = myArray.reduce((obj, key) => {
  obj[key] = true;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log("javascript object:", myObj);
console.log("json string:", JSON.stringify(myObj))
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't use `.reduce()` but that doesn't make this a bad answer. Why the downvote?

Comment: @Pointy Curious as to why you wouldn't use `.reduce()`. Wouldn't it technically be the most algorithmically efficient?

Comment: You're right; I probably would use `.reduce()` - I think I was confused about what the OP wanted when I typed that.

Comment: more elegant solution than using Object.assign with the spread operator. also easier to polyfill if using an old browser.

Comment: @David784 Not sure I would say "more elegant", more *efficient* - yes. Legacy browser compatible - yes. However, OP has ES6 syntax in the code in the original question, so it is safe to assume they are already using polyfills, or are not concerned with supporting legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

use .forEach

```js
let arr = [ 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3' ];
let newArr = {};
arr.forEach(item=>{
  newArr[item] = true;
});
console.log(newArr);
```

however i prefer [mhodges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203321/5674976) answer:

```js
let arr = [ 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3' ];
console.log(Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(item => ({[item]: true}))))
```

Comment: Your result doesn't seem to be in the correct format (I think). OP wanted a single object with each of those keys, not an array of such objects individually.

Comment: oh i see, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `reduce` with `Spread Syntax`

```js
var array = [ 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3' ],
    result = array.reduce((a, c) => ({...a, ...{[c]: true}}), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using `forEach`

```js
var array  = [ 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3' ],
    result = {};

array.forEach(c => result[c] = true);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build the object as you loop the array (one step) and you won't have to replace any braces or brackets.

```js
var ary = [ 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3' ];
var obj = {};
ary.forEach(function(itm) { obj[itm] = true; } );
console.log(obj);
objJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(objJSON);
```