# ES6 Filter/reduce an Object from an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Given**

```
commentIdList = [2,3]
comments = { 1 : "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d" }
```

**Output needed**

```
filteredComments = [ {2:"b"} , {3:"c"} ]
```

**My Unsuccessful try**

```
const filteredComments = comments.filter((c)=> commentsIdList.map(comment=>c.id === comment))
```

Comment: similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203277/how-to-modify-an-array-and-convert-it-to-json/49203304#comment85414075_49203304) but not exactly a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate `commentIdList`. Get the value from `comments` by the key (`id`), and create a new object using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```js
const commentIdList = [2,3];
const comments = { 1 : "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d" }
const filteredComments = commentIdList.map((id) => ({
  [id]: comments[id]
}));

console.log(filteredComments);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way

```
commentIdList.map(commentId => ({ [commentId]: comments[commentId] })
```